# Is the function $f(x)= x(\pi-x)$ $2\pi$-periodic?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the function defined as follows:
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{align}0 \ \ -\pi \le x \le 0 \\ x(\pi - x) \ \ 0 \le x \le \pi \end{align}\right.
$$
$2\pi$-periodic or not?

My attempt:

The function is defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$. First we must check that if $x$ is in $[-\pi,\pi]$, $x + 2\pi$ remains in $[-\pi, \pi]$, which is wrong since

$-\pi\leq x \leq \pi$

$\implies\pi\leq x + \pi\leq 3\pi$

$\implies  x + 2 \pi\in [\pi,3\pi] \text{ and not in } [-\pi, \pi].$

So the $f$ is not $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Looks quadratic to me if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Your function has so far only been defined on an a length-$2\pi$ interval. Exactly one periodic function satisfies the given information.

Comment: If a function is only defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then it is $2\pi$-period if and only if $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. (But being $2\pi$-period on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is not a very informative property. Perhaps you have mis-stated the question?) Your argument is false, because the periodicity or not of a function only depends on its values within its domain $-$ see [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function#Definition).

Comment: Nobody can tell you if the function is periodic unless you give its definition on the whole domain. So far it is defined only on $[-\pi,\pi] $.

Comment: One conventional thing so do is to say "$f$ is the $2\pi$-periodic function with ..." and then write your statement.  It is to be understood that $f$ is defined for all $\mathbb R$ and the other values are obtained using the $2\pi$-periodic property.

Answer (score 1):

It is not $2\pi-$periodic since $f(x)=0$ with $x\in[-3\pi, -\pi]$ an $f(x)\not=0$ $\forall x\in[-\pi, \pi]$.